Cascade hard delete or restore soft deleted entity tree in Hibernate
If we have a large tree of entities connected via foreign keys that was marked soft deleted (all entities annotated with @SoftDelete) by Hiberante, how can we hard delete it or restore it? It would be great to still be able to do cascade hard deletes / cascade restore. It feels at the moment as if @SoftDelete is a one way ticket into soft deletion, yet there seem to be no standard tools to reverse soft deletions (@UnsoftDelete?) or hard delete.
For example, I have a use-case where soft deleted entities should be hard deleted after 30 days or restored on customer request.
